# SSRS - Dynamic Sub-Reports in table(Tablix) for every row

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, subreports

**Scenario:**

I have 5 sub-reports (with different layouts).  All these sub-reports work fine when called individually in main report.

Based on criteria, I need to show any 1 sub-report. All other remaining sub-reports should be hidden. I thought I could achieve this using a table (Tablix) where I would pass the primary key as parameter to show sub-report.

I have dropped all sub reports on each column as shown below, and setting the ***column visibility*** property with an expression like this.

```
=iif(Fields!RptLayoutNum.Value=1,true,false)
```

[image]

So when 1 is true it will show sub-report 1, 2 will show sub-report 2, etc.
So the Final report output will be like this.

[image]

However, this is not working. 
Main report defaults to 1st sub-report layout and I am not able to see other sub-report based on the data.
Appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: What if you set it on the field? Also =iif(Fields!RptLayoutNum.Value=1,true,false) means that if the value is 1, hide the thing, and if not it's visisble.

Comment: RptLayoutNum is a field. It returns anything between 1 to 5. Based on the value it should display that particular sub-report. 

If the dataset returns 4 then show 4th subreport, If it returns 3 then show 3rd.

Comment: So just  =iif(Fields!RptLayoutNum.Value=1,False,True)

Comment: Yes, but its still showing 1st subreport layout, I am not able to see 2nd subreport layout.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The formula says if value = X, then not invisible. What if you add a debug field of that value?